# Building bigrams and trigrams in PHP for spellchecking in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, spell-checking

I am trying to prepare autocomplete with correction with Sphinx and found this article: http://www.ivinco.com/blog/sphinx-in-action-did-you-mean/ , what is very helpful but not so easy to understand.

The questions I have are:

1. How to build this bigrams and trigrams from keywords I already have in my sphinx index?
2. How to prepare the quesry to the Sphinx deamon and not SphinxSE like in the example article.

Does anyone have made such spelling "Did you mean ..." project with Sphinx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should look in the misc/suggest/ folder in the download.

Also viewable here http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/suggest/